# how to auto generate output in excel

Tags: sql, excel

I hv a table like this:-

TABLE A

ID      FIRST_NAME     LAST_NAME        DOB
A001    John           Little          19701020
A002    Tim            Henry           19690105
A003    Alex           Dalton          19730312
A004    Chris          Lee             19720822
A005    Susan          Johnson         19710723

When user input the ID in excel, example A001 in column A2, it will trigger a sql query:-

select * from Table A where ID='A001'

The output will be like this in excel :-

Column A  Column B       Column C        Column D        Column E
A001      A001           John            Little          19701020

How can it repeat the same process if the user input a series of IDs like this:-

Column A 
A001 
A002
A003
A004
A005

Can I use a macro ?

Thanks.

Comment: By what means does entering an ID in Excel trigger a SQL query?

Comment: I'm generating queries from data in excel column & once I hv updated the data in the said column, i'll execute it by pressing a button (with assigned macro).

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how many rows you want to show the user at one time.

The easiest solution is to display only one user in a single row. You can use Microsoft Query to set up a parameterized query that draws its value from a cell in the worksheet, and by checking the box to have the data refresh automatically when the cell value changes, the row you display will change as the user enters different IDs.

If the user wants to enter IDs on multiple rows and have each row populated with the appropriate data, then you might be better off using VBA to retrieve the records and to populate the cells.